# iFrame aspect ratio stuck and will not respond to CSS dimensions

Tags: css, html, iframe

I am trying to embed an iFrame in a content management system which will later act as a preview function when making changes to a page. Trouble is, the iFrame won't change size, and I'm bewildered.

Video link to example: https://www.icloud.com/sharedalbum/#B0b5M7GFPGbX4Tu

How can I make the height responsive to the CSS values I'm entering? What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.videowrapper {
   float: none;
   clear: both;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   padding-top: 25px;
   height: 0;}

.videowrapper iframe {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

<div class="videowrapper">
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="-YOUR-URL-HERE-" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this produces the same effect as when in the video I changed the width to 100%. Still in the dark with this one